# Convert a byte Array to Type from String

Tags: c, xml

I would like to find an elegant solution to solve my problem.
I would like to do a dynamic byte conversion, in a type value defined in String ex. "Int32", "Byte", "UInt16" derived from xml file.

This is an example. is it possible to automate the conversion to remove the Switch Case?

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] data = {77,4}; // (256 * 4) + 77 --> 1101
        object value = ToType(data, "Unt16");
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    unsafe public static dynamic ToType(byte[] data, String typeStr)
    {
        fixed (byte* p = &data[0])
        {
            switch(typeStr)
            {
                case "Int16":
                    return *((Int16*)p);
                case "Unt16":
                    return *((UInt16*)p);
                case "Int32":
                    return *((Int32*)p);
                case "... ...":

                    ....
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this might interest you: [Fun With `__makeref`](http://benbowen.blog/post/fun_with_makeref/), especially "this allows us to treat a struct instance as though it was an instance of another [type]."

Comment: How about a generic function, where the return type is the T? You are doing a decision what value typeStr should be anyway.